# POST Data cleared on returning to previous form page after submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

When I return to the form page after I submit I do a redirect to a thank you page, when I go back the form data usually stays because I check in all fields if post data is set, echo out post data.

If I disable Javascript the post data saves upon returning the the previous page.

So i know it is a JavaScript/jQuery issue.

This is submit handler, any reason why this might be occuring other then the submission handler?

```
        submitHandler: function(form) {
        $(".submit").attr("disabled", true);
        $('#dv-submit, #overlay, #overlay-back').toggle(100); // toggle the "please wait, submitting your request" div
        $('button#btnSubmit').toggle(100); //hide this to prevent multiple clicks and odd behavior
        form.submit();
    }//end submithandler()
```

The weird thing is I have the same submit handler in my other forms and this does not happen.

Comment: Is the console returning any errors?

Comment: no errors, and I am preserving the log. all my form data just gets cleared when javascript is enabled. really odd issue.

Comment: A redirect to another page would be sufficient to break most browser repost-on-refresh behaviour. Setting a cookie on form submit (or a session variable, as you suggest) would also work quite nicely. You could have the form submission page unset the session variable again, such that only a fresh access to the form would permit re-submitting the form

Comment: I am already setting the session on load storing it in a variable and then unsetting it, would that be causing the issue? would you use jquery or php to set cookie or a session? I am currently using php with jQuery validation and it is acting funny, when I disable javascript in dev tools, it works fine.

Comment: Found the issue, the php header() redirect I am doing on each page load to strip out my get parameters after storing them in the post data is the issue, how can I get pass this? I need to redirect to hide the URL GET parameter's but still prevent my form from losing post data on return to the page after submission